# Store user information - Mobile Services Azure

Tags: authentication, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am developing an app where I want to perform user authentication. I would like to create a users table based on the Live, Facebook, Twitter and Google API. Currently I am able to authenticate the users with the mobile service and get the userId and token.
The thing is, I want to store the user information (name, email, profile picture, etc) together with a nickname and an ID. In a table like this:

```
    id    | nickname | authenticationId |  name  |     email     |    pictureUrl  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    01    |  john01  | Google:329743477 |  John  | john@live.com | someurl.com/0123
    ..    |    ..    |        ..        |   ..   |      ..       |       ..
```

The question is, what is the best way (best practice) to store this user information?

Would it violate the law if I were to store them in a mobile service table?

Comment: Have you _tried_ storing them in a mobile service table?

Comment: I can do it, I just ask if this is the correct way.

Comment: Show us what you've tried and tell us what issues you have with it, and you may get answers. You have written your question as if you want us to do your work for you.

Comment: No. I only asked if is possible ("legal") to store this kind of information (name, email, etc) in an ordinary mobile service table or I need something more secure. I am new in Azure. I don't want you to do my work. Sorry if I have been misunderstood, my level of English is not very good.

Comment: You left that impression because I can't think what else could prevent you from storing whatever data you want, wherever you want to store it.

Comment: Maybe by storing a password (but this is not the case). I don't know if some of the information that Live, Facebook, Twitter or Google can give me must be treated specially. If not, great, I will create this user table. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I edited your question to clarify that you are looking for legal advice. Your question will probably be closed soon because this is not a site that can give you legal advice.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no hard requirement that you encrypt this data in your Mobile Service table and nothing to technically stop you from storing it in such a manner.  That said, some of this information is considered [Personally Identifiable Information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personally_identifiable_information) (PII) and as such might bother some people if it was unencrypted (though again, not illegal and many apps do store this data in this way).